# Connect to Hive from Spark without using "hive-site.xml"

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

Is there any way to connect to Hive from Spark without using "hive-site.xml"?

```
 SparkLauncher sl = new SparkLauncher(evnProps);
        sl.addSparkArg("--verbose");
        sl.addAppArgs(appArgs);
        sl.addFile(evnProps.get(KEY_YARN_CONF_DIR) + "/hive-site.xml");
```

We are passing "hive-site.xml" to SparkLauncher.I want to remove dependency on "hive-site.xml"enter code here.

Answer (score 1):

Spark SQL supports reading and writing data stored in Apache Hive. However, since Hive has a large number of dependencies, these dependencies are not included in the default Spark distribution. If Hive dependencies can be found on the classpath, Spark will load them automatically. Note that these Hive dependencies must also be present on all of the worker nodes, as they will need access to the Hive serialization and deserialization libraries (SerDes) in order to access data stored in Hive.

Configuration of Hive is done by placing your hive-site.xml, core-site.xml (for security configuration), and hdfs-site.xml (for HDFS configuration) file in conf/.

When working with Hive, one must instantiate SparkSession with Hive support, including connectivity to a persistent Hive metastore, support for Hive serdes, and Hive user-defined functions. Users who do not have an existing Hive deployment can still enable Hive support. When not configured by the hive-site.xml, the context automatically creates metastore_db in the current directory and creates a directory configured by spark.sql.warehouse.dir, which defaults to the directory spark-warehouse in the current directory that the Spark application is started. Note that the hive.metastore.warehouse.dir property in hive-site.xml is deprecated since Spark 2.0.0. Instead, use spark.sql.warehouse.dir to specify the default location of database in warehouse. You may need to grant write privilege to the user who starts the Spark application.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.MapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public static class Record implements Serializable {
  private int key;
  private String value;

  public int getKey() {
    return key;
  }

  public void setKey(int key) {
    this.key = key;
  }

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}

// warehouseLocation points to the default location for managed databases and tables
String warehouseLocation = new File("spark-warehouse").getAbsolutePath();
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Java Spark Hive Example")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate();

spark.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS src (key INT, value STRING) USING hive");
spark.sql("LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'examples/src/main/resources/kv1.txt' INTO TABLE src");

// Queries are expressed in HiveQL
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM src").show();
// +---+-------+
// |key|  value|
// +---+-------+
// |238|val_238|
// | 86| val_86|
// |311|val_311|
// ...

// Aggregation queries are also supported.
spark.sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM src").show();
// +--------+
// |count(1)|
// +--------+
// |    500 |
// +--------+

// The results of SQL queries are themselves DataFrames and support all normal functions.
Dataset<Row> sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT key, value FROM src WHERE key < 10 ORDER BY key");

// The items in DataFrames are of type Row, which lets you to access each column by ordinal.
Dataset<String> stringsDS = sqlDF.map(
    (MapFunction<Row, String>) row -> "Key: " + row.get(0) + ", Value: " + row.get(1),
    Encoders.STRING());
stringsDS.show();
// +--------------------+
// |               value|
// +--------------------+
// |Key: 0, Value: val_0|
// |Key: 0, Value: val_0|
// |Key: 0, Value: val_0|
// ...

// You can also use DataFrames to create temporary views within a SparkSession.
List<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();
for (int key = 1; key < 100; key++) {
  Record record = new Record();
  record.setKey(key);
  record.setValue("val_" + key);
  records.add(record);
}
Dataset<Row> recordsDF = spark.createDataFrame(records, Record.class);
recordsDF.createOrReplaceTempView("records");

// Queries can then join DataFrames data with data stored in Hive.
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM records r JOIN src s ON r.key = s.key").show();
// +---+------+---+------+
// |key| value|key| value|
// +---+------+---+------+
// |  2| val_2|  2| val_2|
// |  2| val_2|  2| val_2|
// |  4| val_4|  4| val_4|
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks.Will try to enable hive support.

Comment: Does it helpful solution for you?